# Broadcast stream ignoring first events when yield

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add events to a broadcast stream immediately after listen to it. Strangely, the first events are being ignored and only those added after a delay are printed by my listener:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

final streamController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();

Stream<int> yieldedStream() async* {
  yield 0;
  yield* streamController.stream;
}

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final subscription = yieldedStream().listen(print);
  streamController.add(1);
  streamController.add(2);
  streamController.add(3);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  streamController.add(4);
  streamController.add(5);
  streamController.add(6);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  subscription.cancel();
}
```

If the stream is replaced by a non broadcast one, removing `.broadcast`, all numbers are printed. Same deal when I replace `yieldedStream()` by `streamController.stream`.

Why this happens? Is there any way to ensure that all events will be listened without the use of a delay?

Comment: I believe this is by definition. A broadcast stream that is not being listened will just discard anything being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that all events will be listened by adding `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` before sending the first event to the broadcast stream.

```dart
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final subscription = getCounter().listen(print);
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  stream.add(1);
  // ...
}
```

The usage of `Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` is demonstrated a lot in the [bloc package](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) documentation, for example [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=basic-usage-1). The explanation says:

> `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` is added to ensure we wait for the next event-loop iteration (allowing the `EventHandler` to process the event).

Comment: This seems unusual to me. Sounds like there is a bug on dart and this workaround became the standard way to go 

Comment: Yup, I guess it's becoming official though, haha. But after reading [this explanation](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/808#issuecomment-580652828) that behavior does actually make sense. Only problem is probably because there is no special keyword for that.

Comment: It does indeed! But since `listen` method is not `async`, dart language itself is not making this behavior semantically explicit. That's why it seems like a bug or a design error to me 